# sistema de Friendship requests en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

PRIMERO QUE NADA, ESTA PREGUNTA SERA LARGA; de ante mano, muchas gracias por pasarse y tomar su tiempo a leer la pregunta.

He estado trabajando en un sistema de solicitudes de amistad como el de Facebook en CodeIgniter, el problema que estoy teniendo es que no logro averiguar la manera correcta de crear la funcion de follow/add como quieran llamarle.

Digamos que puedo enviar solicitudes de amitad a X usuario pero si ese usuario ya me envio una ami, en lugar de enviar otra solicitud a la tabla, esta deberia de actualizar la solicitud de usuario enviada a mi(o viceversa si yo se la envia a el primero, en lugar de que X usuario me envia una, que actualize la mia).

Hasta ahora la unica manera en la que he estado actualizando las rows es mediante la base de datos directamente...

Aqui una imagen de la base de datos?:
[image: Imagen de base de datos]

Y aqui el codigo HTML y PHP que tengo en el view de profile:

```
<?php
if($item->username == $this->session->username){
   echo '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">You</a>';
} elseif(empty($relationship->status)) {
    echo form_open('users/follow/'.$item->username);

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'friend_id',
        'id' => 'friend_id',
        'value' => $item->id
    );

    echo form_hidden($data);
    echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Follow', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs'));
    echo form_close();
 } elseif($relationship->status == 'accepted') {
     echo form_open('users/unfollow/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->username);

     $data = array(
         'name' => 'friend_id',
         'id' => 'friend_id',
         'value' => $item->id,
     );

     echo form_hidden($data);
     echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Unfollow', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs'));
     echo form_close();
 } elseif($relationship->status == 'pending') {
     echo form_open('users/unfollow/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->username);

     $data = array(
         'name' => 'friend_id',
         'id' => 'friend_id',
         'value' => $item->id,
     );

     echo form_hidden($data);
     echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Cancel', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs'));
     echo form_close();
 } elseif($item->user_id) {
     echo 'Ho.a';
 } else {
     echo 'Cannot follow yourself';
 }
?>
```

Y aqui tengo la funcion de follow/add/agregar amigo, como ustedes quieran llamarle:

```
public function follow($username){

        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('user_id')){
            // Redirect to page
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        // Get item
        $item = $this->User_model->get_username($username);

        // Already friends?
        $friendship = $this->User_model->the_relationship($item->id);

        if ($friendship->status == 'accepted') {

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You are already following this user.');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('users/dashboard');

        } elseif($friendship->status == 'pending') {

            $item = $this->User_model->get_username($username);

            // Page Data
            $data = array(
                'user_id'   => $item->id,
                'friend_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'status'    => 'accepted',
                'type'      => 'friendship'
            );

            $this->Relationship_model->updateFriendship($item->id, $data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You accepted the friendship request.');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('users/dashboard');

        } else {

        // Get item
        $item = $this->User_model->get_username($username);

        // Page Data
        $data = array(
            'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'friend_id'     => $item->id,
            'status'        => 'pending',
            'type'          => 'friendship',
        );

        $this->Relationship_model->add($data);

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
            'type'        => 'friendship',
            'action'      => 'sent',
            'user_id'     => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'message'     => '(' . $this->session->userdata('username') . ') sent a friend request to ('.$item->username.') ',
        );

        // Insert Activity
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Friend request has been sent');

        // Redirect
        redirect('users/profile/'.$item->username);

    }

}
```

He aqui la funcion que tengo en el model que verifica si existe una relacion entre usuarios:

```
public function the_relationship($id){  
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->relationship);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->where('friend_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('type', $this->type);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y muchas gracias a los que decidan ayudarme con este problemita que he tenido ya por varios dias.

NOTE: Aqui una imagen del actual comportamiento!:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo lo que haría es, antes de hacer la petición de amistad, comprobar si el usuario al que se la voy a enviar ya me ha enviado una previamente, y en ese caso la confirmaría en vez de generar una nueva o que el botón de "Enviar solicitud" se convierta en uno de "Aceptar solicitud"

Comment: Pues quiza lo aplique!. Pero ya sera despues debido que al ultimo opte por crear un sistema de seguidores xD. Pero igual, gracias por la sugerencia!.